# Role based salesforce sends in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect

We are doing a saleforce send in marketing cloud using a campaign in slaescloud. This campaign has members of different status namely(approved,clicked,opened etc) when we are doing the salesforce sends by a marketing cloud user of specific role only contacts with approved status are being sent an email. If a salesforce send is done from marketing cloud by a admin marketing cloud user  every contact irrespective of the status is receiving the email.

nmay I know the mapping between the marketing user role and the contact status in the campaign.

Comment: Is your marketing cloud user of specific profile are integrated with salesforce??

Comment: Hi Josyula, sorry for the delay. Yes w e are having  marketing cloud user of specific profile integrated with salesforce. Do you reckon that  the role of the user in marketing cloud effects this feature ?

Comment: I would recommend checking your Marketing Cloud Connector integration to see if "Scope by User" is enabled. That could be one reason why only certain campaigns are showing for users. It might not have anything to do with status rather who owns the campaign. Just a thought.